# Java Copied Array Duplicate Test

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am currently working on a lotto program and I have to make sure that none of the numbers entered by the user are duplicated.

Since I'm a amateur at JAVA, I got really confused.

The idea is that after JAVA finds a duplicated number, I want to amend it and continue the program.

The problem is in this method:

```
public static void getPlayerNamesNumbers(String players[], int playerLottoNumbers[]) {

    int incerment = 0;
    int k = 1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        int num = 1;

        System.out.print("\nName of player " + k + ": ");
        players[i] = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Hi " + players[i] + ", Please pick your 4 Lotto Numbers: ");

        for (int j = 0 + incerment; j < 4 + incerment; j++) { //incerment of +4 is used to place the players numbers in the array 
            boolean validNumber = false;
            System.out.print("Number " + num + ": ");
            playerLottoNumbers[j] = keyboard.nextInt(); //Player Number Input
            if (playerLottoNumbers[j] > 20) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Number, try again: ");
                while (validNumber == false) {
                    playerLottoNumbers[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (playerLottoNumbers[j] > 20) {
                        System.out.print("Invalid Number, try again: ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Number " + num + ": " + playerLottoNumbers[j] + "\n");
                        validNumber = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            num++;                
        }
        int low = (i * 4); //This is the start of each players numbers
        int high = (i + 1) * 4; //This is the end of each players numbers
        int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(playerLottoNumbers, low, high);
        Arrays.sort(newArray);

        System.out.println(players[i] + "'s lotto numbers: " + Arrays.toString(newArray));
        k++;
        incerment = incerment + 4;
    }
}
```

I have found the answer for checking duplicates (Thread Resolved):

```
        for (int j = 0 + incerment; j < 4 + incerment; j++) { //incerment of +4 is used to place the players numbers in the array 
            PlayerLottoNumbers[j] = keyboard.nextInt();


            for (int x = 0 + incerment; x < 4 + incerment; x++) {
                if (j != 0) {
                    if (PlayerLottoNumbers[j] == PlayerLottoNumbers[x] && j != x) {
                        while (PlayerLottoNumbers[j] == PlayerLottoNumbers[x])//if generated number is already an element of the array
                        {
                            System.out.println("Repeated Number, Please Re-Enter Number: ");
                            PlayerLottoNumbers[j] = keyboard.nextInt();//generate new number
                            x = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
```

Comment: please include the code inside the question as text instead of a link (the link can get invalid, the text not)

Comment: Please pinpoint in the code where you are having the issue. Also, don't paste the whole file, just snippets of the issue area and the problem you have

Comment: And what have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use a Set<Integer> and .contains(num) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet of code you have this for detecting if numbers are valid:

```
while (validNumber == false) {
                playerLottoNumbers[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (playerLottoNumbers[j] > 20) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid Number, try again: ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Number " + num + ": " + playerLottoNumbers[j] + "\n");
                    validNumber = true;
                }
            }
```

You also have a way to detect if the number is already in the array in the second snippet.

I'd recommend putting that second snippet into it's own method and calling it in the valid number check. Maybe something called `boolean isDuplicate(int[] numbers, int newNumber)`. You would have to modify it a bit so that the parameters match up with your code.

Then you can call it so that the code above becomes

```
    while (validNumber == false) {
                    int temp = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (temp > 20 || isDuplicate(playerLottoNumbers, temp) {
                        System.out.print("Invalid Number, try again: ");
                    } else {
                        playerLottoNumers[j] = temp;                        
               System.out.print("Number " + num + ": " + playerLottoNumbers[j] + "\n");
                        validNumber = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This way looks a lot cleaner than my original code.